# ARM display to VGA

Tags: assembly, arm

I was wondering where I could find any good resources on learning to display to VGA using the ARM architecture, as I have been searching, and apart from the Wikipedia pages, which help a little, I wanted to find a good basic tutorial or paper.

Thanks

Comment: I would use a Linux distro that supports VGA style output for the exact ARM processor you are going to use (because ARM is quite broad...  ARM9?  Cortex A8? ....) as a first source of information.  Plus of course the CPU manufacturer's own documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am  running a Linux distro, and am coding raw assembly. I plan on loading the code on something lie bochs or qemu since I don't have an ARM arch. But, I have no idea how to play with VGA

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about VGA as in video?

ARM is a processor, not a video chip.  If you want video the discussion needs to be about video which is independent of the processor.  You want to program a peripheral driver, asm is a very bad choice, just write in C or better borrow from the mountains of open source code (in C).

Also we cant have this discussion without knowing what operating system you are going to write this driver for.  Are you talking on the metal (no operating system) or re-inventing a driver for say linux that has already been written?

Assuming on the metal and since you mention qemu (bochs is x86 not arm), find a system supported by qemu that has both an arm processor and emulated video.  Find the documentation for that emulated video be it a chip or some sort of framebuffer.  There is going to be a linux driver for that system so you can use that as a reference.

Arm systems with video are cheap enough you could just by one (ipod classic/video, nintendo gba/nds, open-rd, hawkboard, beagleboard, beaglebone, pandaboard, raspberry pi, etc, etc, the list is very long) some are sub $100.  Do your research before you buy, you may need extra hardware to do development at that level on a platform.

All of that above of course if you are talking about taking existing vga solutions which means you are programming chips and the chips are all different from each other, and the programming of them have little to do with vga itself, that part is all hidden from you, you are just manipulating registers to define the height, width and depth, etc, and then manipulating the pixels in memory.   The processor to peripheral interface also varying from one solution to the next the same video chip can be interfaced to the arm a number of ways so you have all that to deal with.

Programming a gba or nds using visualboyadvance or one of the nds emulators might be a good starting point in general putting pixels on something and talking to a peripheral.

If there is another definition for VGA that you are referring to, please improve your question, even if it is video, please improve your question it is really unanswerable as written.