# ARM Kernel with UI

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, arm

I'm new to OS development and am working on an ARM kernel. I've been using QEMU for emulation (running `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -nographic`).

I have code that, when run with the above qemu flags, acts as an echo kernel. That is, pressing a key causes the key's value to be output to the console at the cursor's location.

My next goal is to be able to draw anywhere on the screen (something along the line of what ncurses can do). So, pseudocode would look like:

```
void draw(int x, int y, char c){
    memory[y*width + x] = c;
}
```

Right now, when I run qemu with the `-curses` or without the `-nographic` flag, it appears to freeze (nothing happens and the qemu keys, `CTRL-<key>`, don't work).

I've tried searching for where screen memory is on versatilepb, but haven't had any luck. I also wasn't able to find out if ARM has a screen location similar to x86's. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418960/arm-display-to-vga) mentioned that ARM doesn't do VGA. I've also tried writing to `0x0C000000`, as mentioned [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0092b/index.html), but that didn't work. Checking `0x0C000008` revealed that it's value is 0, which I think made sense since I was running with `-nographic` at the time.

Essentially, I'm running out of terms to look up and resources to consult, so I need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

[Partial fix](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?p=195000), but not really what I'm looking for since it writes pixel by pixel and not in characters.

Comment: Sounds like you want [/questions/11418960](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418960/arm-display-to-vga).

Comment: **ARM** uses memory mapped I/O.  So a peripheral like video memory is just memory mapped.  If you run without MMU/cache, you just need to find the physical address emulated by QEMU and use that as the address of `memory`.  Most video is memory mapped.  Some displays are *serial* and you write ASCII or some proprietary command format to them; these displays have on-board memory.  It looks like the Versatile boards do not come with video by default; maybe a daughter-board.  So it is not clear what qemu would emulate.

Comment: I agree. I've been trying to read up on this the past couple of days. I'm thinking of going with a realview using a Cortex-A9 chip. I think it has video memory. Still a lot to do though. I'm new to this and am having a hard time finding the memory addresses. (I've been reading the docs.) Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: That OSDev link pretty much says everything you need to know about the hardware. Once you've set up the PL110 and pointed it at whatever bit of RAM you want to use as a framebuffer, that's it. The question is really "how do I write a video BIOS?" - if you want to translate a character array into pixels in a framebuffer, you're going to have to write the code to do so.